# How to mimic table with a colspan=2 layout with CSS div layout

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table layout - 3 cells. Left and right take up 100px, middle is auto sized.

I would like to create a "row" that is split into 2 50% "cells", and put one of the existing 3 cell row in each "cell".

Bad title but hard to describe, but here is what I have so far for the div layout, and below that what I am trying to reproduce for the table layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

    <style>

     .container { width: 800px; margin: 0 auto; }
     p {
        display:table;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 10px 0;
     }
     .left {
        display:table-cell;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: black;
     }
     .mid {
        display:table-cell;
        width: auto;
        background-color: red;
     }
     .right {
        display:table-cell;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: green;
     }


     table { width: 100% }

    </style>
 </head>

 <body>

        <div class="container">

            <h1>DIV</h1>

            <!-- one half -->

            <p>
                <span class="left">aaa</span>
                <span class="mid">aaa</span>
                <span class="right">aaa</span>
            </p>
            <!-- /one half -->
            <!-- one half -->
            <p>
                <span class="left">bbb</span>
                <span class="mid">bbb</span>
                <span class="right">bbb</span>
            </p>
            <!-- /one half -->
            <p>
                <span class="left">ccc</span>
                <span class="mid">ccc</span>
                <span class="right">ccc</span>
            </p>



        <h1>TABLE</h1>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="50%">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="left">aaa</td>
                            <td class="mid">aaa</td>
                            <td class="right">aaa</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td width="50%">
                    <table  width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="left">aaa</td>
                            <td class="mid">aaa</td>
                            <td class="right">aaa</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="left">ccc</td>
                            <td class="mid">ccc</td>
                            <td class="right">ccc</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RmaKW/2/

I thought I could wrap the first 2 "rows" in a simple float: left, width: 50% div but am not having any luck.

Comment: You've got the width of the p tag set to 100% - maybe set the width of the p tag to 50% with float:left and give it a class of "spanned" which sets width to 100%?

Comment: Yes that does answer my question. I tried to make a simple example for this question, but it didn't capture my problem.  The middle cell has a select input (custom jquery control) that I want to fill this space, and when the selected text is really long it no longer does the ellipses on overflow, it always expands to the full text.  I'm going to try another question

Comment: Here's my updated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532835/how-to-hide-overflow-on-select2

Comment: Did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/YvTXT/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="doo">
    <div class="foo">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="foo">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.doo > div {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

div.doo:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

div.foo {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: #eee;
}

div.foo > div:first-child, div.foo > div:last-child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #333;
}

div.foo > div:first-child {
    left: 0;
}

div.foo > div:last-child {
    right: 0;
}

div.foo > div:nth-child(2) {
    padding: 0 100px;
}
```